# Python: How to read in file once but not exhaust iterator in nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

Two input files. Regions input file:

```
Start:  1       id123   1234
Stop:   1       id234   3456
Start:  2       id456   34523
Stop:   2       id231   35234
```

Positions input file:

```
1       123
1       1234
1       1256
1       1390
1       1490
1       3456
1       3560
1       5000
2       345
2       456
2       34523
2       34589
2       35234
2       40000
```

I want to add a third field to the positions file, where the positions fall inside my regions. This is what I wrote, Option 1:

```
regions = open(fileone, 'r')
positions = open(filetwo, 'r').readlines()

for start in regions:
        stop = regions.next()
        a = start.split()
        b = stop.split()
        if 'Start' in a[0] and 'Stop' in b[0]:
                for line in positions:
                        pos = line.split()
                        if pos[0] == a[1] and pos[1] >= a[3] and pos[1] <= b[3]:
                                pos.append("1")
                        else:
                                pos.append("0")
                        print("\t".join(pos))
```

Alternative, option 2:

```
regions = open(fileone, 'r')
positions = open(filetwo, 'r')            

d = {}
for start in regions:
    stop = regions.next()
    a = start.split()
    b = stop.split()
    if 'Start' in a[0] and 'Stop' in b[0]:
            d[a[1]] = [a[3],b[3]]

for line in positions:
    pos = line.split()

    chr = d.keys()
    beg = d.values()[0][0]      
    end = d.values()[0][1]

    if pos[0] == chr and pos[1] >= beg and pos[1] <= end:
            pos.append("1")
    else:
            pos.append("0")
    print("\t".join(pos))
```

Option 1 returns the file twice, with only one region annotated in each repetition:

```
1       123     0
1       1234    1
1       1256    1
1       1390    1
1       1490    1
1       3456    1
1       3560    0
1       5000    0
2       345     0
2       456     0
2       34523   0
2       34589   0
2       35234   0
2       40000   0
1       123     0
1       1234    0
1       1256    0
1       1390    0
1       1490    0
1       3456    0
1       3560    0
1       5000    0
2       345     0
2       456     0
2       34523   1
2       34589   1
2       35234   1
2       40000   0
```

Option 2 just returns all 0 in column 3.

What I would like is a combination of the two, where the second region is also annotated the first go around. I know I could run it once for each region and then combine, but that would get messy with the volume of my real data so I'd rather avoid combining them after the fact. 
Thanks in advance :)

Desired output:

```
1       123     0
1       1234    1
1       1256    1
1       1390    1
1       1490    1
1       3456    1
1       3560    0
1       5000    0
2       345     0
2       456     0
2       34523   1
2       34589   1
2       35234   1
2       40000   0
```

Comment: Please show an example of the desired output.

Comment: It does't have to be nested for loops. I also tried a solution creating a dictionary with the regions file and then using that to look through the positions file, but I'm getting myself confused with how to look up the right thing. 

I will post it underneath, perhaps that is an easier problem to solve.

Comment: Take attention to transform integer strings into integers before comparing. Because strings can be compared but the result are particular: ``'345' < '123'`` is False because ``'3'`` is considered greater than ``'1'`` ; ``'345' < '456'`` is True because ``'3'`` is more little than ``'4'`` ; ``'3458' < '456'`` is True for the same reason ; ``'3458' < '356'`` is True because ``'5'`` is greater than ``'4'``, the first characters being the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose:

```
def one(regions):
    with open(regions,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            a = line.split()
            b = f.next().split()
            assert(a[0]=='Start:' and b[0]=='Stop:')
            assert(a[1]==b[1])
            yield (a[1], (int(a[3]),int(b[3])) )

def two(positions,regions):
    d = dict(one(regions))
    with open(positions,'r') as g:
        for line in g:
            ls = tuple(line.split())
            yield(ls + (1 if d[ls[0]][0]<= int(ls[1]) <=d[ls[0]][1] else 0,))

print list(two('filetwo.txt','fileone.txt'))

print '================================'

print '\n'.join('%s\t%s\t%s' % x for x in two('filetwo.txt','fileone.txt'))
```

.

### EDIT

It seems that the following code does what you ask as an improvement:

```
def two(positions,regions):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in one(regions):
        d[k].append(v)
    with open(positions,'r') as g:
        for line in g:
            ls = tuple(line.split())
            yield ls + (1 if any(x <= int(ls[1]) <= y for (x,y) in d[ls[0]])
                        else 0,)
```

with

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

at the beginning

Comment: Thank you, that is awesome. How does it handle the case where multiple keys have the same name? i.e.

Start:  1       id123   1234
Stop:   1       id234   3456
Start:  1       id789   3600
Stop:   1       id567   3700
Start:  2       id456   34523
Stop:   2       id231   35234

Assuming that the positions file also had these in it. Does this make sense? Thanks again :)

Comment: What do you call 'key' and what do you call 'name'  ?

Comment: Whoa this is incredible! I was calling key the "1" and "2" that the list [start, stop] was mapping to, didn't want to use the word value because I was referring to the actual characters, not what they mapped to (as they are called in dictionary terms, right?). But it seems that you figured it out despite my ambiguous language.

Comment: Not incredible; it's Python, that allows to adapt rapidly a code for a new idea. That's what I like with Python: the possibility to vary very rapidly an algorithm. It's what makes it very productive. Happy to have helped you. - Note that the ``,`` after ``else 0`` is what makes ``(1 if any(.....) else 0,)`` a tuple; this comma is necessary to have two tuples to add, without this one there would be an error.